# How to trigger click event by dropdown value in angular 8

Tags: typescript, events, angular7, angular8, behaviorsubject

My question is simple. Just I am trying to trigger the click event by dropdown value. Depends on the dropdown value's number I want to trigger click event from the header component to the content component. So I have used behavior subject here. But not working.How to find a solution. If anyone knows please help me.

If you see my demo you can easily understand my question. Please check the demo.

Demo:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-bootstrap4-navbar-fjy7jc?file=src/app/content/content.component.html

header.component.ts:

```
  getDDVal(e){ 
   let ddValue=e.target.innerHTML; 
   let number = parseInt(ddValue.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''), 10); 
   this.commonservice.changeMessage(number); 
  }
```

content.component.ts:

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.elList.forEach((item, index) => { 
      if (index === this.geteventMsg ) (item.nativeElement as HTMLElement).click(); 
    }); 
 }

 ngOnInit(){  
    this.commonservice.currentMsg.subscribe(geteventMsg => this.geteventMsg = geteventMsg); 
    console.log("Header=",this.geteventMsg); 
 }
```

common.service.ts:

```
 private messageSrc = new BehaviorSubject(0);
 currentMsg = this.messageSrc.asObservable(); 

 changeMessage(message: number) {
    this.messageSrc.next(message);
 }
```

header.component.html:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" *dropdownMenu role="menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" (click)="getDDVal($event)">
<li>
   <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="redirectUrl('Test 0')">Test 0</a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="dropdown-item" (click)="redirectUrl('Test 1')">Test 1</a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="dropdown-item" (click)="redirectUrl('Test 2')">Test 2</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is exactly your problem? The stackblitz seems to work for me.

Comment: @akop: I want to trigger  click event for radio button when we select on navbar dropdown..Example if you select test 0 from dropdown you want to trigger the test 0 radio button click event..same for others

Comment: @akop:Are you clear now?

Comment: Not really. When In your stackblitz: When I click the radioButton, then the event get called correctly. So I don't see your problem.

Comment: @akop: What is happening on if you click radio buttons.. samething should be happen if you select dropdown value

Comment: If no button for the radio-button exists then a button will be created and in the console appears `Click event: testX` where X is the correct number.

Comment: @akop:  here checking index  (index === this.geteventMsg )